# How can I get the Android soft keyboard to overlay my website?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem that seems pretty simple to me, but so far it was impossible to find a simple solution: On my website, whenever the Android soft keyboard pops up, it resizes the window and shrinks the content, instead of just overlaying the page.

See these pictures for reference: [image: website screenshot]

The first two are the current situation, the third is what I want. It works like this on iOS. What can I do to make it work that way?

---

The screenshots were taken in Firefox - this is a website based on HTML, not a native app.

I tried setting body size and position, but so far, no luck. I've seen some very complicated JS code snippets for similar problems, but I didn't get any of them to work the way I want, and it also seems like there should be an easier way around it. The sizes of all the elements are determined with `vh` and `wv`. Setting fixed pixel values seems like it would kill the responsiveness of the design, no?

I'm not a very experienced developer, my page is just very basic HTML and CSS. Is there a way to achieve what I want with only that?

Comment: What do we see: your html page displayed in a WebView of your app? Or what? Where?

Comment: It's a HTML page, viewed through Firefox on Android.

Comment: You should have told that before as people think that it is your app and start talking about manifest file of it. Did you try other browsers?

Comment: Yes, it's the same for the standard brwoser on my Samsung phone, as well as Firefox inside Telegram, Firefox Standalone and Chrome.

Comment: Sorry, I thought mentioning that it's a website in the title was enough. I'll clarify that in the question.

Comment: You should say sorry at that answer i think as you have no app yourself but only some html.

Comment: I wouldn't say the [tag:android] tag is appropriate for this question, the volunteers who answer the questions use the tags to search for topics within their area of expertise, so you are just attracting Android developers to your post.

Answer (score 2):

On your `manifest.xml` you can set `android:windowSoftInputMode` to `adjustPan`.

```
<activity
 android:name=".WebActivity"
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
```

From Android documentation:

> Don't resize the window to make room for the soft input area; instead
> pan the contents of the window as focus moves inside of it so that the
> user can see what they are typing. This is generally less desireable
> than panning because the user may need to close the input area to get
> at and interact with parts of the window

Comment: I don't have a manifest.xml yet, can I add this to a simple HTML page like this? It's not a native app.

Comment: Then this not and Android relation question, but try this: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1"> or <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=no">

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought that since it's a question related to Android-specific stuff the tag would be appropriate.

Comment: Yes the `android` tag is ok as you try to get your html code ok for Android browsers.

Comment: Sadly not, the keyboard still resizes the window. This seems to be an intended behavior that has been made pretty hard to circumvent, at least that's what I got from several other questions I read on here.I decided to leave it for now. Your second suggestion for the meta tag made it look a bit better by keeping the space around the input fields intact, which is nice. Thanks for that!

Comment: This is what I am looking for ``android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`` thanks